# 64k limit for NotesJSONNavigator?

Tags: json, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I'm currently testing the new Domino V10 LotusScript NotesJSONNavigator classes, and trying to parse long strings using this code:

```
dim session as New NotesSession
Dim jsonReader as NotesJSONNavigator
Dim stream as NotesStream

Set stream = session.CreateStream
stream.WriteText("*** Populate stream with long JSON here ***")

stream.Position = 0
Set jsonReader = session.CreateJSONNavigator(stream.ReadText)
```

Once the stream contains more than 64k of text, the final line of code produces an error as follows:

"Unable to Parse JSON string:
Missing a closing quotation mark in string, offset 65535."

If there is a 64k limit, this is a real shame, because the performance of NotesJSONNavigator appears to be very good. Is there any workaround for this if so?

Comment: I have created a case with HCL #TS001812200

Comment: A trial on Domino 12.0.1FP1 seems to suggest this is now fixed.